# Create 'once emitting' observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using using RxJS (version 6+) to switchMap to another observable which needs to be emitting one value to start the pipe(line).

The current solution is using:

```
const saveAction$ = new Observable(observer => {
            observer.next();
        }).pipe(switchMap(() => this.saveAction()))
```

which creates an observable that immediately emits.
The `this.saveAction()` returns an `Observable<void>` which contains some synchronous code and a return of a call to the HttpClient.
The `saveAction$` is being saved in a redux store which will be called when another component dispatches the `handleSaveChanges`.

Another option would be using `of(true)`, but the `true` has no value here, because it would not be used.
Using a `Subject` would be another option, but the overhead of a subject is not needed, because I need it to only emit **once** and then complete.

There is an `EMPTY` (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant that gives an observable that completes, but never emits. It would be much nicer if there was something like `ONCE`, instead of using the constructor.

Are there other ways, which are cleaner, to solve this problem?

Comment: Are your store events available as an observable source? Wouldn’t that be the proper trigger for this observable? `saveChanges$ = this.reduxStore.events$.pipe(filter(e => e.type === 'handleSaveAction'), switchMapTo(this.saveAction))`

Answer (score 3):

The [`EMPTY`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L8) constant's definition is single line

```js
export const EMPTY = new Observable<never>(subscriber => subscriber.complete());
```

You could try to define your own `ONCE` as following

```js
export const ONCE = new Observable<any>(subscriber => subscriber.next());
```

It could then be used as

```js
ONCE.pipe(switchMapTo(this.saveAction()))
```

which essentially is the same as your solution.

Answer (score 2):

To comment your thought

> Another option would be using of(true), but the true has no value
> here, because it would not be used

When you `observer.next()`, it in-fact does get a value too - `undefined`. It is also not used. So based on this, option with `of(null)` is a simple and straightforward way. I don't find this confusing and used this approach quite few times.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic is, what should `ONCE` emit for a value? This value has to be provided. That the consumer doesn't need that value is a different story, but the source has to provide *something* if it calls `next()`.

Due to this fact, the shortest way to write this IMHO would be (as you already mentioned)

```
of(true)
```

If you need some more values, where the values and / or count is already known beforehand I would go with something like

```
from([true, false, true, false])
```

Or using something to create the array beforehand (loops, LINQ, etc) and using this.

Only when you're going to need to emit values at runtime from something *not-observable* I would take some kind of `Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Observable2 = Observable1.pipe(first())
```

The Observable will only emits the first value then close itself.
Here is the [doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first).

Comment: The operator has its use, but the problem I'm having here is that I need to 'create' an observable, I do not have an Observable1 that emits something yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what redux store are you using ?

Comment: A really late response, but I'm using Akita (https://datorama.github.io/akita/) because the customer has mostly .NET developers and this is easier to understand using services instead of the whole Redux pattern

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly:

If `this.saveAction()` already returns an observable, why not return it instead of the `new Observable()`, and use `take(1)` ([docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take)) so it'll emit only once?

Something like that:

```
const saveAction$ = () => this.saveAction().pipe(take(1))
```

You can then use `this.saveAction()` subscription wherever it's needed:

```
saveAction$.subscribe()
```